# What to call a small partnership company on my resume

Tags: resume, company-culture

I have just started a small company offering small IT solutions (statistical analysis, web design, etc.) for companies.

We are two owner of the company, so it's not a sole proprietorship company. I don't know how to speak of my ownership on my cv. I don't want it to sound too pretentious and I want to clearly emphasize that it's a small company started by myself, so I am not sure if Managing Partner is appropriate.

As a description, I have written that it's a self-owned company. Are there any business terms to classify my situation. It is indeed a partnership and I hope the business will grow to have employees some day, so it's definitely not a sole proprietorship.

Comment: Are you marketing the *company* or *yourself*?  If you are marketing the company, you don't distribute a **resume**.

Answer (score 5):

The standard title to user here is "**Founder**" or "**Co-founder**". In your case you probably want to emphasize that it's not a solo project to give it more credibility and weight so you could use the latter term, but on a CV "Founder" is probably used more often.

For more details, consult [this answer on Startups SE](https://startups.stackexchange.com/a/830) which also has several links to more detailed pages.

The only thing you'll want to avoid is suggesting that the company is larger than it really is by using C-level titles like CIO or CFO by themselves. If there truly is that kind of division between the founders and you want to reflect that "Founder and CxO" is common.

Finally, keep in mind that you don't want to represent yourselves as managing employees if it's *only* a 2-man freelancing company. But that is something to note in the actual description of your work, not the title or header.

Answer (score 0):

It is a "corner case" because of the size of the company, where titles moreover C-type ones are tricky. Eg if there is one accountant is he a CFO?
I would add the fact that the company is a small one and something that you do on the side in an additional sentence next to the company on the CV.